# Problem using Distinct Mysql - Duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to select multiple meta_keys with SQL, but using DISTINCT is not working to prevent duplicated values.

Here's the SQL Query i'm using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT lat.meta_value as lat, lat.post_id, lng.meta_value as lng
FROM wp_postmeta lat join
     wp_postmeta lng
     on lat.post_id = lng.post_id and
        lat.meta_key = 'billing_cpf' and
        lng.meta_key = 'billing_profissao'
        WHERE lng.meta_value = 'Médico(a)'  
ORDER BY `lat` ASC
```

It returns duplicated values for lat.

Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it returns duplicated values for `lat`.  That is how `select distinct` works.  It returns distinct *rows*, not *columns*.

If you want one row per `lat`, then use `group by`.  But you need aggregation functions.  For instance:

```
SELECT lat.meta_value as lat,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT lat.post_id) as post_ids,
       GROUP_COCNAT(DISTINCT lng.meta_value) as lngs
FROM wp_postmeta lat join
     wp_postmeta lng
     on lat.post_id = lng.post_id and
        lat.meta_key = 'billing_cpf' and
        lng.meta_key = 'billing_profissao'
        WHERE lng.meta_value = 'Médico(a)'  
GROUP by lat.meta_value
ORDER BY `lat` ASC;
```